# Does somebody maybe know the name of this psychological phenomenon?

Tags: medication

Suppose that I need to take medication because of my symptoms. When taking medication, then I'm better. Then I think that I do not need medication because I am feeling well. So I stop taking medication. Now my symptoms get worse because I stopped taking medication for them. So I go back to taking medication.

Does somebody maybe know what this psychological phenomenon is called? ChatGPT says it is the "non-compliance circle" but I can not find anything when I google for that term. Thanks for any ideas and replies!

Comment: Your question caused me to do some research. I don't have an answer to your question. But I discovered the other causes of medication non-adherence (such as forgetfulness, cost) also do not have particular labels, they are just described. I also could not find anything which mentioned circle/cycle aspect of non-adherence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rebound cycle is relatively well known but often considered a result of the flawed thinking involved in a mental illness. Some call it noncompliance, others non-adherence but it is understood in psychology that patients often feel better and stop taking medication on a cycle. The key is learning that you’re doing better because of medication not in spite of it. It is not really considered a phenomenon as much as a learning curve to overcome with clients.

https://natashatracy.com/treatment-issues/noncompliance/why-mental-illness-stop-taking-medication/